# Closing Second Window that is created in MainWindow WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an address book app. I currently have MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="AddressBook.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AddressBook"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Width="100" Height="50" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0 0 0 50" Click="Button_Click">New Contact</Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="50" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 0 0 50">Edit Contact</Button>
    <Button Width="100" Height="50" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0 0 0 50">Delete Contact</Button>

    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvContacts" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" >
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" ></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" ></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" ></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AddressBook
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        NewContact newContact;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Contact> items = new List<Contact>();
            items.Add(new Contact() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
            items.Add(new Contact() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
            items.Add(new Contact() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" });
            lvContacts.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            newContact = new NewContact();
            newContact.Show();
        }        
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the "New Contact" button it creates a second window called "NewContact.xaml"

```
<Window x:Class="AddressBook.NewContact"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AddressBook"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="NewContact" Height="348.322" Width="516.107">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>           
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Title Label Column-1 Row-1 -->
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Black">New Contact</Label>

    <!--First Name-->
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">First Name</Label>       
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" ></TextBox>

    <!--Last Name-->
    <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2">Last Name</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>

    <!--Address-->
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4">Address</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="5"></TextBox>

    <!--Email-->
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6">Email</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="7"></TextBox>

    <!--Phone Number-->
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8">Phone Number</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9"></TextBox>

    <Button x:Name="Submit_Button" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" Width="75" Height="25" Margin="0 20 0 20">Submit</Button>
    <Button x:Name="Cancel_Button" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="10" Width="75" Height="25" Margin="0 20 0 20" Click="Cancel_Button_Click">Cancel</Button>


</Grid>
```

I want the user to be able to close NewContact window when they click the Cancel_Button.

My first thought is to do the following, but I can't figure out how to properly implement it and I know I am missing something or don't understand how this should work and need some guidance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AddressBook
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NewContact.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NewContact : Window
    {
        public NewContact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Cancel_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewContact NewContact = new NewContact();
            NewContact.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Window Close method to close it which manually closes a window.
So in the "Cancel_Button_Click" for the button you can just use "Close();" instead of creating a new instance of it's own class and close that.

Comment: Thanks! I was just typing this as I saw your comment come in. I marked yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out and it is a simple solution.

```
private void Cancel_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Close();
    }
```

I was overthinking the problem.